# pass string variable from view to controller in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller, action

my view is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#Body').redactor({

    fileUpload: "@Url.Action(controllerName: "RedactorUpload", actionName: "FileUpload")"
            , autoformat: false
            , convertDivs: false
            , direction: 'rtl'
            , autoresize: false
});
```

my action in controller is:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowUploadSafeFiles]
        public virtual ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file,string section)
        {
            ActionResult result;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string relativePath = "/Content/"+section+"/Files/";
            string absolutePath = Server.MapPath("~" + relativePath + fileName);

        if (file.ContentLength > 0 && fileName != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs(absolutePath);
            var array = new { filelink = relativePath + fileName, filename = fileName };
            result = Json(array, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Content("invalid file!");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I want to send section from my view to action. section is string variable. relativePath variable in action is dynamic and is determined from view (by parameter is passed from view).

Comment: Great! So what error are you getting?

Comment: no error- I want solution for that. solution for passin string variable from view to controller

Comment: My first thought would be learn to code...That said, with MVC4 if you want to pass multiple variables as parameters of an `ActionResult` you will need to define a custom route in your `routes.config` file